# Entity Framework Core cannot create a DbSet because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I'm working with Entity Framework Core, and changed the default culture.

Please help me find a solution to resolve the problem: the first time I call the API with culture language, it requires using that language on the controller.

When I changed to another language, it will throw error:

> Cannot create a DbSet because this type is not included in the model for the context

But when using the language, when I had called it the first time, it worked okay.

I have only seen that problem on a special class.

And this is the code in the `DbContext`:

```
public virtual DbSet<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }
```

**Update: that error only for table include name "charge", with that table i change to any name, it worked ok. But i don't want change it, so how can i do for resolve this problem?**

Some pics hope everybody known my problem in this case

1. First time change default CultureInfo with "en-US"

[First time change default CultureInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIteg.png)

2. When i change to other language and set default `CultureInfo`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSmtp.png)

3. When I change to set `CultureInfo` to `en-US` (same first time):

[When change to set CultureInfo to "en-US"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdY9V.png)

Comment: Can you please add some more code about what you're doing here... It's not really to understand.

Comment: thanks you for comment, i had add some pic hope you know